# Reconstruct the source file from string output

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte, steganography

I use [stepic3](https://github.com/luisivan/stepic3) to hide some data. Multiple files are compressed into a zip file, which will be the hidden message. However, when I use the following code

```
from PIL import Image
import stepic

def enc_():
    im = Image.open("secret.png")
    text = str(open("source.zip", "rb").read())
    im = stepic.encode(im, text)
    im.save('stegolena.png','PNG')

def dec_():
    im1=Image.open('stegolena.png')
    out = stepic.decode(im1)
    plaintext = open("out.zip", "w")
    plaintext.write(out)
    plaintext.close()
```

I get the error

> Complete Trace back
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\Pyhton Projects\Kivy Tests\simple.py", line 28, in   enc_()
>   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\Pyhton Projects\Kivy Tests\simple.py", line 8, in enc_
>   im = stepic.encode(im, text)
>   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\Pyhton Projects\Kivy Tests\stepic.py", line 89, in encode
>   encode_inplace(image, data)
>   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\Pyhton Projects\Kivy Tests\stepic.py", line 75, in encode_inplace
>   for pixel in encode_imdata(image.getdata(), data):
>   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\Pyhton Projects\Kivy Tests\stepic.py", line 58, in encode_imdata
>   byte = ord(data[i])
>   TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

There are two ways to convert to a string.

```
text = open("source.zip", "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()
```

with output

```
PKn!K\Z

sec.txt13 byte 1.10mPKn!K\Z

sec.txtPK52
```

or

```
text = str(open("source.zip", "rb").read())
```

with output

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00n\x8f!K\\\xac\xdaZ\r\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00sec.txt13 byte 1.10mPK\x01\x02\x14\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00n\x8f!K\\\xac\xdaZ\r\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00sec.txtPK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x005\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I used the second and I got the same string back from the retrieval.

In order to reconstruct the zip file (output is string), I use the code

```
plaintext = open("out.zip", "w")
plaintext.write(output)
plaintext.close()
```

but the written file says is corrupted when I try to open it. When I try to read what was written to it, with either

```
output = output.encode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')
```

or

```
output = bytes(output, 'utf_8')
```

the output is

```
b"b'PK\\x03\\x04\\x14\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00n\\x8f!K\\\\\\xac\\xdaZ\\r\\x00\\x00\\x00\\r\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x07\\x00\\x00\\x00sec.txt13 byte 1.10mPK\\x01\\x02\\x14\\x00\\x14\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00n\\x8f!K\\\\\\xac\\xdaZ\\r\\x00\\x00\\x00\\r\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x07\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xb6\\x81\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00sec.txtPK\\x05\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x01\\x005\\x00\\x00\\x002\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"
```

which is different from the source file.

What do I have to reconstruct the embedded file faithfully?

Comment: Please post the complete traceback.

Comment: I edited the question, with complete traceback

Comment: A word of caution. Stepic hasn't been adapted properly for python 3. `ord()` and `chr()` don't work in the same way as in python 2 and that's because the distinction between bytes and strings the former has introduced. This is evident in the gymnastics we have to go through to get the desired result in python 3, as demonstrated in my answer. It'd be more natural to do away with `ord()` and `chr()` and just work with bytes. Even more worryingly, you can get wrong results using these functions in python 3. `ord('€') = 8364`, while the program embeds only one byte per character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a file in `rb` mode, you'll get a byte array. If you print it, it may look like a string, but each individual element is actually an integer.

```
>>> my_bytes = b'hello'
>>> my_bytes
b'hello'
>>> my_bytes[0]
104
```

This explain the error

> > "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\Pyhton Projects\Kivy Tests\stepic.py", line 58, in encode_imdata byte = ord(data[i]) TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

`ord()` expects a string, so you have to convert all the bytes to strings. Unfortunately, `str(some_byte_array)` doesn't do what you think it does. It creates a literal string representation of your byte array, including the preceeding "b" and the surrounding quotes.

```
>>> string = str(my_bytes)
>>> string[0]
'b'
>>> string[1]
"'"
>>> string[2]
'h'
```

What you want instead is to convert each byte (integer) to a string individually. `map(chr, some_byte_array)` will do this for you. We have to do this simply because stepic expects a string. When it embeds a character, it does `ord(data[i])`, which converts a string of length one to its Unicode code (integer).

Furthermore, we can't leave our string as a map object, because the code needs to calculate the length of the whole string before embedding it. Therefore, `''.join(map(chr, some_bytearray))` is what we have to use for our input secret.

For extraction stepic does the opposite. It extracts the secret byte by byte and turns them into strings with `chr(byte)`. In order to reverse that, we need to get the ordinal value of each character individually. `map(ord, out)` should do the trick. And since we want to write our file in binary, further feeding that into `bytearray()` will take care of everything.

Overall, these are the changes you should make to your code.

```
def enc_():
    im = Image.open("secret.png")
    text = ''.join(map(chr, open("source.zip", "rb").read()))
    im = stepic.encode(im, text)
    im.save('stegolena.png','PNG')

def dec_():
    im1=Image.open('stegolena.png')
    out = stepic.decode(im1)
    plaintext = open("out.zip", "wb")
    plaintext.write(bytearray(map(ord, out)))
    plaintext.close()
```